# How to set the error even after cross checked in yaml editor

Tags: ansible

ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON or YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/java.yaml': line 2, column 8, but it may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```yaml
-hosts: localhost
 become: yes
       ^ here[root@ip-172-31-32-55 ansible]# cat java.yaml
```

```yaml
-hosts: localhost
 become: yes
 tasks:

 -name:Install Java package
   yum:name={{ item}}
   with_items:
    -java
    -maven
    -git
```

---

I tried to execute java.yaml file but I'm not getting desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the online validators. For example, [YAML Lint](https://www.yamllint.com/). The correct syntax is below

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install Java package
      yum:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - java
        - maven
        - git
```

See:

- [Ansible YAML Syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-syntax)
- [YAML Ain’t Markup Language (YAML™) Version 1.1](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/current.html)
- [Ansible lint rules](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/lint/rules/)